# Can't remap `<D-p>` in iTerm2

Tags: neovim

I'm configuring neovim using iTerm2 on mac.
When trying to remap `<D-p>` (Cmd+p) I only open the print view.

```lua
local telescope_builtin = require('telescope.builtin')
-- Doesn't work
vim.keymap.set('n', '<D-p>', telescope_builtin.find_files, {})
-- Does work with Ctrl+p
vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-p>', telescope_builtin.find_files, {})
```

Update:

I tested `<D-y>` (Cmd + y) which isn't mapped yet and it also doesn't work.

```lua
-- Doesn't work
vim.keymap.set('n', '<D-y>', telescope_builtin.find_files, {})
```